# Text inside Breadcrumb class is not responsive - CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am styling a breadcrumb css with width 100%, but the text inside it, is not responsive. The text inside the breadcrumb class goes out in small screen device.

Here is the css:

```
.breadcrumbs
{
background-color:#ECF0F1;
padding:10px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
margin-bottom:5px;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
white-space: nowrap;
}
.breadcrumbs a{
    color: #8A793E;
}
```

I know i am missing something. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Use **vw** units for the fonts. The font-size will then adjust itself to the width of the viewport. Here's the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/75ffcjkh/

Comment: either remove `white-space: nowrap` so the lines will wrap, or adjust the font size like @Sudipto suggested or hide parts of the breadcrumb via `@media` queries so it will display

Comment: oh thanks. removing nowrap works.